# Get notified when my friend goes live on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications, facebook-live-video

Some time ago, when watching a friend's live video, Facebook presented me with an option something like "get notifications whenever this user goes live" - this was probably in the iOS app.

I chose this for a number of my friends before noticing that in fact it seemed to do exactly the opposite - any time I chose it for a friend, from then on I no longer got notifications when that friend went live.

This situation has persisted and I never get notifications anywhere (desktop, mobile...) when any of those friends go live, whereas I do when other friends go live.

I can't find any option to reset this or enable notifications for the friends in question. Anything I can do?